# How to make a nicer summary table instead of verbatimTextOutput in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am wondering if there is an easy solution to producing a nicer summary table in R shiny (i.e. instead of the verbatim code output, a table that looks similar to when you insert a csv file and display its contents). I basically want an easier to read/formatted version than the code that it outputted.

I know broom::tidy() usually serves this purpose, but I am getting the error: Columns 1 and 2 must be named.

Here is some code. I have just been using the iris.csv dataset.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(broom)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  myData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  })
  
  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(myData())       
  })
  
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(myData()) %>% 
      tidy()
  })
  
  

  
}


ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv',
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                         '.csv')),
      uiOutput('select')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('contents'),
      verbatimTextOutput('summary')
      
    )
  )
)
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not a direct solution , but quick one is to use  shinytheme described at https://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/ . This will make shiny content prettier including tables . Example: ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("spacelab"), ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few edits I made:

1. the way of calling `tidy()` is to call it directly on the dataset; `summary(myData()) %>% tidy()` throws errors even in a non-Shiny context
2. make the 'summary' element be a table, similar to the 'contents' table

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(broom)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  myData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  })
  
  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(myData())       
  })
  
  output$summary <- DT::renderDataTable({
      tidy(myData()) %>% 
      DT::datatable()
  })
  
  
  
  
}


ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv',
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                         '.csv')),
      uiOutput('select')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('contents'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('summary')
      
    )
  )
)
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image: shiny plot]

Update: if you really really want to use `summary()`, you could replace `tidy(myData()) %>%` with:

```
myData() %>% 
  summary() %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  separate(sep = ":", into = c("var", "value"), col = c(1)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), str_trim), value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
```

Comment: Note the warning message when calling `tidy()` on a `data.frame`: "Warning message: Data frame tidiers are deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release of broom" [`broom` v1.0.5].  Nice catch though: I didn't realise that `tidy()` summarises a `data.frame` - I just assumed it would return the `data.frame` unaltered.

Comment: @Limey I saw that! But it doesn't say what to do instead -_-

Comment: IMHO, the answer is "do nothing".  The current behaviour is a side effect and not what `tidy` is "expected" to do.  On that basis, OP's question is really "How can I `tidy` the output from `summary`?".

Comment: @Limey updated it! did something similar to what you considered doing

Comment: Thanks both! I had a few issues with columns that weren't numeric, so I ended up going with: `myData() %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% tidy(myData()) %>% DT::datatable()` if any future users have this issue

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem with `broom`.  I'd report it to the authors.

There is some useful info earlier in the messages printed alongside the error message you quote:

```
Warning message:
'tidy.table' is deprecated.
Use 'tibble::as_tibble()' instead.
```

So let's try `as_tibble` instead, using the `iris` dataset to keep things minimal...

```
> as_tibble(summary(iris))
Error:
! Columns 1 and 2 must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Caused by error in `repaired_names()`:
! Names can't be empty.
✖ Empty names found at locations 1 and 2.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Hmm.  That didn't work either.  We need to think a little.  `as_tibble` is a S3 method.  So let's find the method that is actually called in this case.

```
cls <- class(summary(iris))
> cls
[1] "table"
> getS3method("as_tibble", cls)
function (x, `_n` = "n", ..., n = `_n`, .name_repair = "check_unique") 
{
    if (!missing(`_n`)) {
        warn("Please pass `n` as a named argument to `as_tibble.table()`.")
    }
    df <- as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    names(df) <- repaired_names(c(names2(dimnames(x)), n), repair_hint = TRUE, 
        .name_repair = .name_repair)
    as_tibble(df, ..., .name_repair = "minimal")
}
<bytecode: 0x7fc54fff2ca8>
<environment: namespace:tibble>
```

A little experimentation shows that the error is thrown by

```
df <- as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`as_tibble` is a short function and the fix is easy.  In this case, we can write:

```
as_tibble(
  as.data.frame(
    summary(iris), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
    name_repair = "universal"
  )
)
# A tibble: 30 × 3
   Var1  Var2            Freq             
   <chr> <chr>           <chr>            
 1 ""    " Sepal.Length" "Min.   :4.300  "
 2 ""    " Sepal.Length" "1st Qu.:5.100  "
 3 ""    " Sepal.Length" "Median :5.800  "
 4 ""    " Sepal.Length" "Mean   :5.843  "
 5 ""    " Sepal.Length" "3rd Qu.:6.400  "
 6 ""    " Sepal.Length" "Max.   :7.900  "
 7 ""    " Sepal.Width"  "Min.   :2.000  "
 8 ""    " Sepal.Width"  "1st Qu.:2.800  "
 9 ""    " Sepal.Width"  "Median :3.000  "
10 ""    " Sepal.Width"  "Mean   :3.057  "
# … with 20 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

But I don't think that's a particularly helpful format.  You may find something like

```
iris %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -Species,
    names_to = "Var",
    values_to = "Col"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Var) %>% 
  summarise(
    Min = min(Col),
    Q25 = quantile(Col, probs = 0.25),
    Median = median(Col),
    Mean = mean(Col),
    Q75 = quantile(Col, probs = 0.75),
    Max = max(Col)
  )
# A tibble: 4 × 7
  Var            Min   Q25 Median  Mean   Q75   Max
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Petal.Length   1     1.6   4.35  3.76   5.1   6.9
2 Petal.Width    0.1   0.3   1.3   1.20   1.8   2.5
3 Sepal.Length   4.3   5.1   5.8   5.84   6.4   7.9
4 Sepal.Width    2     2.8   3     3.06   3.3   4.4
```

more useful.  Adding the summary for the `Species` factor will be easy if you need it, but the best way to do it will depend on the final format you want.